# Find minimum datetime while using FK in two different tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables:

```
COURSE
------
Id
Name

TEST
------
Id
CourseId (FK to `COURSE.ID`)
DATETIME
NUMBERS
```

Suppose `COURSE` table with `ID` 1,2 (only 2 columns) and `TEST` table with 8 numbers of data having different `DATETIME` and `CourseId` of 1 (3 columns) and 2 (6 columns).

I want to find the minimum `DATETIME,CourseID` and `Name` by joining these 2 tables. The below query is giving a 2 output:

```
(SELECT  min([DATETIME]) as DATETIME ,[TEST].CourseID,Name
    FROM [dbo].[TEST]
    left JOIN [dbo].[COURSE]
    ON [dbo].[TEST].CourseID=[COURSE].ID GROUP BY CourseID,Name)
```

I want a single column output i.e. a single output column (minimum datetime along with Name and ID)..HOW can i achieve??

Comment: 'but i want a single query to find the single column??', in your COURSE table have 2 records, so the query always return that 2 Courses with the Minimum date of that course. If you want a particular Course record only , then you have to filter the Course table (WHERE CourseID = ?  ). If you are looking something diff, then please include your expected output also in your question.

Comment: Your example was not clear. Provide sample data and also the expected data from your sample data.

Comment: It looks like you're confusing columns and rows in your question description - perhaps as others have suggested, you could provide a clear example of input data and expected output to allow people to help you? Take a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i want the min datetime along with CourseID and Name

Comment: any suggestion?

Comment: suppose there are more than one courses there in that minimum date, what will be the output?

Comment: yes there are more then one courses  i.e. it may be 1 or 5 or 10..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 2 courses you are always going to get 2 rows when joining like this. It will give you the minimum date value for each course. The first way you can get a single row is to use `TOP 1` in your query, which will simply give you the course with the earliest test date. The other way is to use a `WHERE` clause to filter it by a single course.

Please run this sample code with some variations of what you can do, notes included in comments:

```
CREATE TABLE #course ( id INT, name NVARCHAR(20) );

CREATE TABLE #Test
    (
      id INT ,
      courseId INT ,
      testDate DATETIME -- you shouldn't use a keyword for a column name
    );

INSERT  INTO #course
        ( id, name )
VALUES  ( 1, 'Maths' ),
        ( 2, 'Science' );

-- note I used DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE()) to simply get some random datetime values
INSERT  INTO #Test
        ( id, courseId, testDate )
VALUES  ( 1, 1, DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE()) ),
        ( 2, 1, DATEADD(HOUR, -2, GETDATE()) ),
        ( 3, 1, DATEADD(HOUR, -3, GETDATE()) ),
        ( 4, 2, DATEADD(HOUR, -4, GETDATE()) ),
        ( 5, 2, DATEADD(HOUR, -5, GETDATE()) ),
        ( 6, 2, DATEADD(HOUR, -6, GETDATE()) ),
        ( 7, 2, DATEADD(HOUR, -7, GETDATE()) ),
        ( 8, 2, DATEADD(HOUR, -8, GETDATE()) );

-- returns minumum date for each course - 2 rows
SELECT  MIN(t.testDate) AS TestDate ,
        t.courseId ,
        c.name
FROM    #Test t 
        -- used inner join as could see no reason for left join
        INNER JOIN #course c ON t.courseId = c.id
GROUP BY courseId , name;

-- to get course with minimum date - 1 row
SELECT TOP 1
        MIN(t.testDate) AS TestDate ,
        t.courseId ,
        c.name
FROM    #Test t 
        -- used inner join as could see no reason for left join
        INNER JOIN #course c ON t.courseId = c.id
GROUP BY t.courseId , c.name
ORDER BY MIN(t.testDate); -- requires order by

-- to get minimum date for a specified course - 1 row
SELECT  MIN(t.testDate) AS TestDate ,
        t.courseId ,
        c.name
FROM    #Test t 
        -- used inner join as could see no reason for left join
        INNER JOIN #course c ON t.courseId = c.id
WHERE t.courseId = 1 -- requires you specify a course id
GROUP BY courseId , name;

DROP TABLE #course;
DROP TABLE #Test;
```

Comment: yes ..But i want the total minimum datetime in TEST table along with Name and ID..what should i do??

Comment: "With 2 courses you are always going to get 2 rows when joining like this. It will give you the minimum date value for each course...."..YES THIS IS MY PROBLEM..What should i do??how to solve??

Comment: to be fair, I think I've given the question a fair bash based on what I can interpret from your question. If this doesn't help, please use my re-runnable sample code and show us what output you require, as I don't understand what you are looking for if it's not in my answer.

Comment: @manoj have you even run my code or read the comments in the code?

Comment: sir i want a userdefined function..passing @courseId parameter fetch minimum datetime,id and name

Comment: @manoj so why didn't you ask that in the question? the last query with a where clause should work for that if you pass the courseid as a parameter to a function.

Comment: can you write down the userdefined  function along with @courseId  pass input??

Comment: You do good job..i Appreciate with your query..can you write down the userdefined function along with courseId pass input??

Comment: @manoj see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx

Comment: Create FUNCTION [dbo].[Test]
(@courseId int)

returns @ReturnTable table ([DATETIME] datetime,courseId int,name nvarchar)

AS
BEGIN
 return (SELECT
        MIN(t.[DATETIME]) AS [DATETIME] ,
        t.courseId ,
        c.name
FROM    [TEST] t 
        -- used inner join as could see no reason for left join
        INNER JOIN [COURSE] c ON t.courseId = c.id
  where t.courseId =@courseId
GROUP BY t.courseId , c.name   );
      
END

Comment: while executing A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context. error comes..any suggestion?

Comment: any modification??where should i change??

Comment: Sir actually my requirement is that ...i want to write a simple query just like select ID,Name,(getdata(ID)) from [dbo].[COURSE]

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, you want to return the minimum date from the entire table with the course details of that day.
Please try the below script

```
SELECT TOP 1 MIN(t.testDate) OVER (ORDER BY t.testDate) AS TestDate ,
        t.courseId ,
        c.name
FROM    Test t 
        INNER JOIN course c ON t.courseId = c.id
ORDER BY t.testDate
```

Comment: Create FUNCTION [dbo].[Test]
(@courseId int)

returns @ReturnTable table ([DATETIME] datetime,courseId int,name nvarchar)

AS

 return (SELECT
        MIN(t.[DATETIME]) AS [DATETIME] ,
        t.courseId ,
        c.name
FROM    [TEST] t 
        -- used inner join as could see no reason for left join
        INNER JOIN [COURSE] c ON t.courseId = c.id
  where t.courseId =@courseId
GROUP BY t.courseId , c.name   );

Comment: .can you write down the userdefined function along with courseId pass input??