# How to add validation around dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]

Student can select any number of `CourseBatchCode`,

in Case 3 CourseBatchCode is selected 
This is my Table I want to put validation on the table that

1)ENDTIME should not be between following Start time and end time

2)EndTime should be less than following Start Time and End time

Comment: please post sample table data as text and explain with examples

Comment: This is the Data itself .IF validations are nt true then Print error messege

Comment: please check this link on how to ask good questions:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @TheGameiswar wouldn't it be better to link to an SO post to demonstrate a better way to ask rather than an external site?

Comment: @Tanner:This link explains stuff in simple and clear way,so i referred that link

Comment: on site alternative to show how you can create sample code that users can run: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41587048/57475

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that EndTime is after StartTime **for a given row** then you can use a check constraint like so;

```
ALTER TABLE [YourTableName] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [startBeforeEnd]
CHECK (
    [EndTime] > [StartTime]
)
```

If you want the check constraint to work across rows you would have to use a Trigger, or maybe create a UDF (User Defined Function) and use this in the Constraint - *however* these are usually discouraged because it is easy to cause logic and performance problems with them.

The recommended approach in these cases is to do this type of validation on the client (application) side and not worry about it in the database...